# Active Record in_batches vs find_in_batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to perform batch operations on millions of records from DB.

According to the ActiveRecord documentation, there are two methods to perform batch operations, namely `#find_in_batches` & `#in_batches`. But, I can't seem to find any difference between them except that one returns an `Enumerator` and the other an `ActiveRecord Relation`.

So, considering they have different performance, I want to know which performs better in which scenario. And, is there any better way to conditionally update millions of rows except the raw SQL ?

Comment: Using `.update_all` and updating the rows all at once is always going to outperform pulling records out of the database and updating them one by one by an order of magnitude. If possible this should absolutely be your first choice.

Comment: I'd first ask why they would expose both methods if one is always better than the other (just because one calls the other doesn't mean it's less performant, it just depends on the use case). As @max said, `update_all` is preferred. If you are having some issue (timeout, etc), then spanning your batches across multiple workers could be something to look at.

Comment: `#in_batches` is a lower level function that can be used to build stuff like `#find_in_batches` I doubt that using `#in_batches` will actually be noticeably faster once you actually start iterating through the records. Anyways its like comparing two horse breeds against a space ship. Don't be afraid of a little raw sql. Its not automatically evil.

Comment: Due to some limitation, I can't use raw sql and since the values to be updated are dynamic based on the row, update_all cannot be used as well.

Comment: @VatsalJain if you can, would you please describe your specific case in your question.

Comment: "since the values to be updated are dynamic based on the row" - that sounds like something that actually can be done with SQL. You can use subqueries, functions, lateral joins etc.

Comment: Ok, so I have two tables, say A & B which cannot be directly joined as they reside in different database. And I have to migrate data from A to B based on a common column. The common column is obtained by performing multiple joins in each of the database for A and B

Comment: I'm looking for an efficient way to solve this, as the operation is to be performed on millions of rows.

Comment: Depends a bit on the database but on postgres your can use Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW) to join a table that resides on another database as if it where on the same database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, `find_in_batches` yields each batch of **records** that was found while `in_batches` yields **ActiveRecord::Relation** objects.

So the following code:

```
Post.find_in_batches do |group|
   group.each { |post| puts post.title }
end
```

Will only send one query per batch to database to retrieve all posts' data for the batch:

```sql
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ...
```

However:

```
Post.in_batches do |group|
   group.each { |post| puts post.title }
end
```

Will send two queries per batch to database. The first query to get posts' ids for the batch:

```sql
SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" WHERE ...
```

And the second query to get all posts' data for the batch:

```sql
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ...
```

More details:

If you look in to the source code for those two functions [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L128), you will see that `find_in_batches` actually calls `in_batches` with `load: true` passed in the argument. However the default value for `load` is `false` in `in_batches`.

And if you look further in the `in_batches` for the part that uses value of `load`, it will look like this:

```rb
        if load
          records = batch_relation.records
          ids = records.map(&:id)
          yielded_relation = where(primary_key => ids)
          yielded_relation.load_records(records)
        else
          ids = batch_relation.pluck(primary_key)
          yielded_relation = where(primary_key => ids)
        end
```

Original explanation can be found here: https://www.codehub.com.vn/Difference-between-find_in_batches-vs-in_batches-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Comment: Original explanation link is broken for me.

Answer (score 5):

You must look at the source to understand the performance difference here -

```
def find_in_batches(start: nil, finish: nil, batch_size: 1000, error_on_ignore: nil)
  relation = self
  unless block_given?
    return to_enum(:find_in_batches, start: start, finish: finish, batch_size: batch_size, error_on_ignore: error_on_ignore) do
      total = apply_limits(relation, start, finish).size
      (total - 1).div(batch_size) + 1
    end
  end

  in_batches(of: batch_size, start: start, finish: finish, load: true, error_on_ignore: error_on_ignore) do |batch|
    yield batch.to_a
  end
end
```

Notice how the method `in_batches` is being called and the result is being stored in an array. This is going to take up more memory. `in_batches` is hence a more efficient way here.

Comment: Without any context I agree. But, just because one calls the other doesn't mean it's less performant...it just depends on the use case, which is currently unknown.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord's find_in_batches and in_batches methods are similar in many ways, but there are some subtle differences between them.

The find_in_batches method returns an enumerator that allows the processing of the records in batches defined by the specified batch size. This method is useful when you need to iterate through large sets of records and want to process them one batch at a time. It returns a set of records as an array on each iteration.

```rb
Model.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |batch|
   # Process batch of 1000 records
end
```

In contrast, the in_batches method returns an ActiveRecord relation representing each batch of records as a query. This allows you to chain additional queries before performing an operation on each batch. The in_batches method is also useful when you want to perform a batch operation, but also need to filter or sort the records before processing them.

```rb
Model.where(some_condition: true).in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |batch|
   # Process batch of 1000 filtered records
end
```

Regarding performance, the difference between the two methods is generally negligible. Both methods are optimized to handle large datasets and perform efficient database queries.

As for conditionally updating millions of rows without using raw SQL, ActiveRecord provides convenient methods for that. You can use the update_all method to update multiple records with a single update query. You can use additional conditions to restrict which records are updated.

```rb
Model.where(some_condition: true).update_all(column_name: new_value)
```

This code would update all records in the Model model where some_condition is true, setting the value of the column column_name to new_value.

Remember that when performing batch operations on large datasets, it is important to consider the impact on the performance and resource utilization of the database. Make sure you are using appropriate indexes and that queries are optimized for the task at hand. In some cases, using raw SQL may be necessary for the best performance, but try exploring the ActiveRecord options first, as they provide a safer and less error-prone abstraction.